# How to set style for title inside PageHeader?

Tags: css, antd

```
 <PageHeader className="site-page-header" title={title} subTitle={subTitle} {...(onBackClick !== undefined ? {onBack: () => { onBackClick() } } : {})} />
```

And

```
.site-page-header {
  border: 1px solid rgb(235, 237, 240);
  background-color: #253655;  
}
```

How can I set the color of title (or any text) in this element to another color (from default black)? I tried to set every `color` related field I could find in `.site-page-header` but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the elements to see why the color prop is not passed down to the title reveals that the class .ant-page-header-heading-title has a color prop which has higher specificity. Either add the !important to the color or increase specificity e.g.

```
.site-page-header .ant-page-header-heading-title {
  color: blue;  
}
```